# How to select distinct with ID on the result?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to select distinct from table including ID column on the result?

Like for example: (this is error query)

```
SELECT ID,City,Street from (SELECT distinct City, Street from Location)
```

The table Location

```
CREATE TABLE Location(
ID int identity not null,
City varchar(max) not null,
Street varchar(max) not null
)
```

Then it will show the column ID, distinct column City, distinct column Street

Is there a possible query to have this result?

Comment: Yes, but you need to tell us first **which** id you want (assuming that it's not unique, otherwise, just add it to the `SELECT` list after `DISTINCT`)

Comment: Do you want multiple ids for unique data?

Comment: You need to define which ID you expect to see for any unique combination of city and street. The biggest ID? The smallest? The average, median, ...?

Answer (score 2):

If you want for instance the lowest id for the unique data you desire you can do

```
select min(id), City, Street 
from Location
group by City, Street
```

Generally you have to tell the DB what id to take using an aggregate function like `min()` or `max()`